# JIRA SOAP addAttachmentsToIssue method code example

Tags: php, soap, jira

Could someone show me an example of working php code to add attachment to a JIRA issue via SOAP?

[JIRA addAttachmentsToIssue method](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/service/IssueService.html#addAttachmentsToIssue%28com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->soapClient->addBase64EncodedAttachmentsToIssue($this->token, $this->issue->key, array('test.txt'), array(base64_encode('test')));
```